# I want to add some option in the bottom of listview like whats app?

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview

i want to add some option in the bottom of listview like whatsapp have like invite and help option .Is it possible to override the listview of  last item and give diff feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView footer using [addFooterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)).

Comment: is it possible in grid view? in my gridview i have 3 rows and 4 coulms,in third row i have only 3 views.so i want add something in finally (3*4) position

Comment: Sure, you can place it as the last item of you source list or create a logic on getView from adapter.